what is the difference between all these docker volumes?
I am learning Docker and i am now on volumes and i have a few questions, i made a python scripts that returns a text file and i wanted to save it just to learn how to use the volumes, i used this route:
/home/karen/Documents/:/python
and it worked, then, i searched on internet more about volumes and i found how to save the mysql data but its syntax confuses me, why is it like that?
./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
why is not it lke the python file one?
so i tried to the python one like the mysql one but it did not work
and is ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql the same as /var/lib/mysql:./mysql ?
im really confused, i thought there was only one way to make the volumes

Both of those are directory on local filesystem and a directory inside the container, separated by a colon (:) in the middle. What part of it do you think is different?

These examples you provided are 'local_path' : 'path_in_container'.  If you don't understand what a path like ./mysql is, then that's a basic unix (and for that matter DOS) thing.  The "." indicates "same directory" which is relative to the current directory the docker-compose.yml is in. So it expects that in your project directory, there is a local directory named mysql.

@gview thanks for answering, so, ./mysql is a folder that is in the same folder where Dockerfile is located? ok, i get that, now i have a question, what is the difference between these? /home/karen/Documents/:/mysql   ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql.
and allso can i save the db data in the this local host path? var/lib/mysql

@GuyIncognito i read that this ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql and this  /home/karen/Documents/:python are not the same, i read in the first route the ./mysql is in the same folder as the dockerfile and the one is the path inside the image, and that means im storaging the /var/lib/db in the .,/mysql folder, right?
so, using this, /home/karen/mysql_data:/mysql   is the same as  ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql ?
obiusly knowing that the ./mysql is another folder and /mysql_data another one, i just changed the paths and i want to know if that is okey, and if its ok,

Again, the path on the left side of the : is the local path.  Usually a container has a configuration where it expects to store files, so that is what is going to be on the right.  There are ways to override that within the container by passing parameters, but typically you don't do that.  So really the only thing you are interested in, is where on your local system you will be storing the data.  For databases, you usually don't want to mount a local drive this way.  Instead make a docker volume from the cli with docker volume create mysql-data .  Then specify mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql


why is not it lke the python file one?

The difference here is absolute vs relative paths - thats not specifically a docker thing, its just a feature of operating systems / file systems. Which you use is largely upto you and how you plan to use the container, where you want to store your data etc.
If you use relative paths you must be in the correct directory before running any docker ... commands that use relative paths. ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql would work if there was a directory called mysql in the current directory. Also any directory you specify to docker on the host must exist - relative or absolute path.
If your mysql directory has an absolute path of /home/karen/mysql you could update your volume to: /home/karen/mysql:/var/lib/mysql. Then it doesnt matter where you run the docker command from, the path will always point to /home/karen/mysql

/ at the start of a path means its an absolute path (starting from the root of the file system).
. at the start of a path means is relative to the current directory.
.. at the start of a path means "the parent directory" relative to the current directory.

(if you run ls -lah you will see the . and .. hidden folders)
Here are a few examples in bash of relative and absolute paths - but the same principals apply anytime your using paths - config files, volume arguments to docker etc. or bash
Jump 2 directories "up" with ../..:
karen@host:/home/karen$ cd ../..
karen@host:/$

This is the same as
karen@host:/home/karen$ cd ..
karen@host:/home$ cd ..
karen@host:/$

But the quickest way to the root is with the absolute path /
karen@host:/home/karen$ cd /
karen@host:/$

Use an absolute path to go to a specific directory
karen@host:/tmp$ cd /home/karen/Documents
karen@host:/home/karen/Documents$ 

Mix and match absolute and relative paths:
karen@host:/home/karen$ cd /home/karen/Documents/../mysql
karen@host:/home/karen/mysql$ 

(notice you end up at the absolute path /home/karen/mysql from my relative path that pointlessly traverses Documents\..\ to make a point :)
If you use absolute or relative paths is a choice, there is no right a wrong answer.

i thought there was only one way to make the volumes

Then theres also named volumes - but for now i would stick with mounting folders - with relative or absolute paths to your taste.
There is only 1 way of defining a mounted volume - with a valid path
